What can be said about linear mappings $L(x) = x - \frac{ b^t x }{ b^t a } a$
Suppose that $a, b \in \mathbb R^n$ are non-zero vectors. We define a linear mapping $L :\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$:
$$ L(x) := x - \frac{ b^t x }{ b^t a } a $$
If $b = a$, then this is an orthogonal projection. In general, we can verify

$b^t L(x) = 0$, so $L(x)$ is always orthogonal to $b$
If $x \perp b$, then $L(x) = x$
$L(a) = 0$

Apparently, this is a projection. I am wondering what type of projection. Is this the general form of an oblique projection onto a hyperplane? This construction seems very basic but I have not found any context and discussion in the literature.


I have put this picture as it might help you understand this better.
This is exactly in the form of orthogonal projection of a vector onto a vector if $a = b$.
Using the properties of orthogonal projection onto a vector in our figure, you get
\begin{align}
 w &= u - Proj_v(u)\\
   &= u - \frac{v^\top u}{v^\top v}v
\end{align}
Now compare this to your scenario where you have
$L(x) := x - \frac{b^\top x}{b^\top b}b$ when $a=b$. You can see that $x = u, b = v$. From here you should be able to follow the statements in your question,
$L(x) = w$ which is orthogonal to $v$ or $b$.
If $x$ is orthogonal to $b$, or from our fig, $u$ is orthogonal to $v$, you can see that $L(x) = x$, or $ w = u$ in the fig.
The third statement just follows after plugging in or also follows from a similar figure where you project $a$ onto $a$.

Yes, it is an oblique (non-orthogonal) projection, following lines parallel to $a$ to their intersection with the hyperplane $b^\top x = 0$. (Note that $L(w+ta)=w$ for any $w$ with $b^\top w=0$ and any scalar $t$.)
